# Symfony forms for Translatable Doctrine entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have a Doctrine entity that has been translated using the [Translatable Doctrine extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions):

```
<?php
namespace Myapp\ProductBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_property")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity()
 */
class Property implements Translatable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *   targetEntity="PropertyTranslation",
     *   mappedBy="object",
     *   cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    private $translations;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     * Used locale to override Translation listener`s locale
     * this is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property
     */
    private $locale;


    public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }

    public function getTranslations()
    {
        return $this->translations;
    }

    public function addTranslation(PropertyTranslation $t)
    {
        if (!$this->translations->contains($t)) {
            $this->translations[] = $t;
            $t->setObject($this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to render a form with an input field for the "name" property in each of the languages available in my translation.

How is that best done?

Comment: Did you try creating a PropertyType class that extends AbstractType to build your form? You can specify the translation_domain. Check here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/form.html#translation-domain

Comment: Yes, the `translation_domain` specifies the translation domain used for the labels of the form. The question here is how I add fields that lets me enter several translations of the `name` field at once, for example 3 fields: "Name - English", "Name - German", "Name - French".

Comment: Yes, you can use `translation_domain` in order to specify translation file. FOSUserBundle seems to implment this system very well. FormType: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php   Translation: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/translations

Comment: I am not trying to translate the form labels or orher static texts on the site. I am trying to save the form data - i.e. what Doctrine saves in the database. See my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14125419/112756

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the following bundle is able to do exactly what I was looking for: https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle

[image]

Comment: This bundle is in a low maintenance (maybe no more maintained). Not sure it is a good idea to use it in this freeze state.

Comment: Looks like it is still maintained; the [current last commit is from June 2019](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle/commit/408b60f21865e188743e0097f100ad50ae4b4522)

Comment: You can try my bundle for Entity Localizations. https://github.com/Warxcell/EntityTranslationsBundle

Comment: https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle still working in 2021 with Symfony 5