# How to construct forms with translations for fields from an ORM system (for PHP)?

Tags: database, forms, symfony, orm, internationalization

Some of the popular software libraries can [help to generate forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#form-types) (for data input) to some degree.
The form fields (or form types) can be constructed based on information which is provided also by an object-relational mapping.

I am looking for ways to achieve translated data displays for field labels and descriptions according to such a software combination.

I would appreciate your advices.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is asking us to find you a library, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow. have a look at [Translatable in Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/translatable.md). This should provide a good starting point. When you have concrete problems when implementing translatable form fields, feel free to open a new question.

Comment: I am using some software libraries for a while already.  
I am looking for specific software extensions for my use case.

The communication system “Stack Overflow” informed me about “You have reached your question limit” a moment ago.  
How will the chances evolve that I can contribute a follow-up question?

Would you like to add any further advices according to translatable form fields?

Comment: Looking for specific extensions often leads to subjective answers, because multiple libs can fit the use case, so there is not one "right" answer. This is why SO discourages them. I just wanted to let you know why it might get closed. I don't know about the question limit and if it's time based or not. Usually there is a link with additional info somewhere when something like that pops up. I am not sure what further advice to give regarding the library, other than it seems to fit your use case well. Feel free to edit your question with questions/problems and I will see if I can answer them.

Comment: How do you think about to clarify design options for example based on the software library “Symfony” (for the programming language “PHP”)?

Comment: Sorry, but you are asking for a bit much, especially if I don't have anything concrete to go on. If you like, I can send you the contact details for my conpany's sales rep and then you can book me for a consultation ;)

Comment: Will the clarification of software development possibilities be continued also according to topics like the following?
* [Symfony forms for Translatable Doctrine entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124748/symfony-forms-for-translatable-doctrine-entities)
* [A2LiX Translation Form Bundle](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle)

Comment: Will the clarification for a related question like “[How to translate data models by the means of Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66636139/how-to-translate-data-models-by-the-means-of-symfony)” evolve in helpful ways?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you took a look into [FormType Field Reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#label-format).
You can use that cofiguration:

```
// instead of 'label'
$profileFormBuilder->add('address', AddressType::class, [
'label_format' => 'form.address.%name%',
]);

$invoiceFormBuilder->add('invoice', AddressType::class, [
'label_format' => 'form.address.%name%',
]);
```

And Then, add the following code to your translations file:

```
form:
    address:
        address: Your Address # 'address' replaced %name%
        invoice: Your Invoice Address # 'invoice' replaced %name%
```

Comment: * Does the selected label format influence field translations?
* Are there any other system configuration options to consider for the translation of class attributes (or properties) according to object-relational mappings?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This supports only your form labels translation.

Comment: I  would like to translate a bit more data besides form labels.

Each data field can eventually provide helpful meta-information, can't it?