# How to translate data models by the means of Symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony, localization, internationalization, field

I would like to present another description for a general use case.

Form fields (or form types) can be generated like the following.

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class registration_form extends AbstractType
{
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
  $builder->add('address_street');
 }
}
?>
```

The label “*Address street*” is accordingly displayed then on a test web page so far.
I would like to achieve that translated information will be shown on demand.

Thus I imagine that I need to pass dedicated parameters for the execution environment so that translated data will be retrieved from selected information sources and applied instead of the specified input field name.

Would you like to add any further ideas for such an application according to known key words?

- national language support
- internationalisation
- localisation
- translation

See also:
[Symfony forms for Translatable Doctrine entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124748/symfony-forms-for-translatable-doctrine-entities)

How will the chances evolve to [improve the software documentation for the involved function arguments](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/99a1d4cd2620d3ade86f69d5f65a76b50031b943/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilderInterface.php#L12) so that data models (and corresponding form fields) can be translated in easier and safer ways?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you took a look into [FormType Field Reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#label-format).
You can use that configuration:

```
// instead of 'label' you can use 'label_format'
$builder->add('address_street', null, [
    'label_format' => 'form.%name%',
]);
```

And Then, add the following code to your translations file:

```
form:
    address_street: Your Translated Label # 'address_street' key replaced %name%
```

Comment: I became curious if [the support for “translatable objects”](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translatable-objects) will evolve further.

Are there any more dependencies to consider if XLIFF files would be preferred for some data field translations?

Comment: You can use XLIFF files for your translations. It's a good practice according Symfony Team.
This is its format : 

https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/xliff.html#adding-notes-to-translation-contents

And how your files should be named : messages.en.xlf, messages.fr.xlf, etc.

Comment: [Can data fields (or related member functions) be translated](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40473) even without the specification as named additions to form constructions?